# find maximum corresponding column for maximum value after group by

Tags: python, pandas

For my haves:

[image: "g1", "g2", "value"]

I want to find the key values for the maximum value whilst grouping by g1 and g2 to get these wants:

[image]

This is my current possibly (?) clumsy code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [0, 1, 1, 3],
    'g1': ["b", "b", "c", "c"],
    'g2': ["a", "a", "a", "a"],
    'key': ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
})
print(df)

stats = df.groupby(["g1", "g2"])["value"].max().reset_index()

pd.merge(df, stats, left_on=["g1", "g2", "value"], right_on=["g1", "g2", "value"], how="inner")
```

Any improvement suggestions would be very much welcome please. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't so narrow as to be off-topic, but you will benefit from showing more of the contextual code around this snippet. Otherwise reviews will be more constrained than they probably should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recognise that your first pass should not be to find the group maxima: it should be to find the *indices* of the group maxima. From there it is easy to index into the original dataframe to retrieve the desired maximum rows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': (0, 1, 1, 3),
    'g1': ('b', 'b', 'c', 'c'),
    'g2': ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
    'key': ('1', '2', '3', '4')
})

imax = df.groupby(['g1', 'g2']).value.idxmax()
result = df.loc[imax]
```

However, your original dataframe construction has an issue. If `key` is truly a key, you should be using it as your index instead of the implicit numeric-range index:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': (0, 1, 1, 3),
    'g1': ('b', 'b', 'c', 'c'),
    'g2': ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
    'key': ('1', '2', '3', '4')
}).set_index('key')

imax = df.groupby(['g1', 'g2']).value.idxmax()
result = df.loc[imax]
```